# No funciona método callable en java

Tags: java, poo, hilos

Muy buenas. Estoy haciendo una aplicacion que me diga los números del 1 al 100 divisibles entre dos con el método callable. En el invokeAll del main me está dando error y no sé a qué se debe, agradecería si alguien me podría echar un cable.

Aquí dejo la clase creada para el calculo

```
static class division implements Callable<Integer> {
    private int num;
    private int num1 = 0;

    public division(int num) {
        this.num = num;
        //this.num1 = num1;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            num1 = num1 + 1;
            System.out.println(num1);
        }

        return num1;

    }}
```

A continuación dejo el main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<ej5> llistatasques = new ArrayList<ej5>();

for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++) {
    ej5 divide = new ej5();
    llistatasques.add(divide);
}
List<Future<Integer>> llistaresultats;

llistaresultats = executor.invokeAll((llistatasques));
executor.shutdown();

for (int i = 0; i < llistaresultats.size(); i++) {
    Future<Integer> resultat = llistaresultats.get(i);
    try {
        System.out.println("Resultado"+ i + " es " + resultat.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el texto completo de la traza del error.

Comment: Muy buenas. Ya encontré el error. No estaba llamando al objeto division en el main, si no que estaba llamando a la clase ej5 y por eso me estaba dando error en el main. a continuación dejo respuesta con un solución. No es la mejor pero es útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución. En el main se estaba llamando a la clase a la que pertenecía el objeto y no al objeto, dado a eso me estaba dando error. A continuación dejo el main modificado junto con la clase. No es la mejor solución pero sirve para lo que necesitaba hacer. Un saludo.
clase del objeto;

```
package hola;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.*;

public class ej5 {

static class division implements Callable<Integer> {
    private int num;
    private int num1 = 0;

    public division(int num) {
        this.num = num;
        // this.num1 = num1;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            num1 = num1 + 1;
            System.out.println(num + " Es divisible por 2");
        }

        return num;

    }

}}
```

Clase main:

```
package hola;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import hola.ej5.division;

public class app {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<division> llistatasques = new ArrayList<division>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        ej5.division divide = new division(i);
        llistatasques.add(divide);
    }
    List<Future<Integer>> llistaresultats;

    llistaresultats = executor.invokeAll((llistatasques));
    executor.shutdown();

    for (int i = 0; i < llistaresultats.size(); i++) {
        Future<Integer> resultat = llistaresultats.get(i);
        // try {
        // // System.out.println("Resultado" + i + " es " + resultat.get());
        // } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // // TODO: handle exception
        // }
    }
}}
```